# Shortlisting contacts with complete address

Tags: search-results, custom-search, addresses, search-builder

How do I search in the contacts search / Advanced search that I get only contacts with complete postal address?

I have many contacts in civicrm. Some have only city and country names, which is not very useful in terms of sending postal mailings. So how do I get the results in which I get the contacts with complete address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the search builder to search for empty fields, e.g. Steet-Address or ZIP Code. From the result, you could create a (smart) group and then exclude contacts in that group from the mailing.

Comment: I think 'serach generator' means Search Builder which you find under the Search link in the Admin Menu

Comment: Suppose I have few groups. And in each group, I need contacts with complete address separately, how do I get that?

Comment: Thanks Pete, I changed it to Search Builder.
@ParthibarajRajasekar: You would use the Include-Exclude Search (yoururl.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=4&reset=1), include your main group(s) and exclude your "no postal address group". The result would then be all contacts taht match your main group's criteria minus those without a postal address. If you make the groups smart, you do not have to build the search again every time you use it.